# NSOperationQueue and sending delegate to main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hi i have my class Sensors where i have gps,gyroscope,accelerometer and i want o send data in delegate from nsoperationqueue:

```
@protocol SensorsDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)motionManagerDidAccelerateData:(CMAccelerometerData *)accelerometerData;
@end


- (void)startAccelerometr
{
    if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {

        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/10.0;
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.operationQueue 
          withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
            }
            else {
                [self.delegate motionManagerDidAccelerateData:accelerometerData];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

How to send data to delegate which is in main thread ?? Or send acceleremoter data ?

Answer (score 2):

Put `onMainThread:` method in the same class and change your code like this

```
- (void)startAccelerometr
{
        if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {

        self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/10.0;
        [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.operationQueue 
          withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
            }
            else {
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMainThread:)
                  withObject:accelerometerData waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
        }];
    }
}

- (void)onMainThread:(id)accelerometerData{
    [self.delegate motionManagerDidAccelerateData:accelerometerData];
}
```

Comment: I'll check it tommorow but seems to look very nice +1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using

```
[self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(motionManagerDidAccelerateData:) withObject:accelerometerData waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Ues delegate don't have performselector in main thred :/ i used notofication center fonally

Comment: You can performSelectorInMainThread as long as your delegate is defined as NSObject<delegate>* instead of id<delegate>. For some reason, id is just an untyped pointer, and not a shortcut to NSObject.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

Assuming that delegate is a property of type `NSObject<SensorDelegate>*` assigned at Sensor init method:

```
[self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(motionManagerDidAccelerateData:) withObject:accelerometerData waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change the queue you are sending the accelerometer updates to the main queue.

```
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
```

Comment: I don't want to use accelerometer in main thred !